# Using Artifactory plugin for Jenkins, is there a way to search repos for images with a property?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm using the Artifactory plugin in Jenkins. I have a situation where I need to pull docker images from Artifactory which have a particular property set. I can search for them using the REST API, but I have not found a way to do this using the Jenkins plugin. Anybody know if there is a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the download spec schema from the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=102334624):

```
{
  "files": [
     {
       "pattern" or "aql": "[Mandatory]",
       "target": "[Mandatory]",
       "props": "[Optional]",
       "recursive": "[Optional, Default: true]",
       "flat" : "[Optional, Default: false]"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Where from my point of view you have a couple of options to search by propeties; one would be using `aql` where you have such option. Second one would be directly using `props`, which main purpose seems to be exactly that:

> **props:** List of "key=value" pairs separated by a semi-colon. (For
>   example, "key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3). Only artifacts with
>   all of the specified properties and values will be downloaded.